# How to config SharedPreferences for the first run activity in the Android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

**I have 3 Activity:**

1- SplashScreensActivity

2- IntroActivity

3- MainActivity

I need to do, At First launch appliation start IntroActivity else MainActivity after SplashScreenActivity .

**Edited:**

I wrote this code but did not work and after showing Splash Screen, MainActivity Started and IntroActivity never start.

Plese let me to know where is the problem.

Intro.Java:

```
    SharedPreferences settings=getSharedPreferences("prefs", 0);
    final boolean firstRun=settings.getBoolean("firstRun",false);
    if(firstRun==false)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=settings.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstRun",true);
        editor.commit();
        Intent i=new Intent(Intro.this,Intro.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
    else
    {
        Intent a=new Intent(Intro.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(a);
        finish();
    }
```

SplashScreeActivity.Java:

```
public class SplashScreensActivity extends Activity {

private ImageView mLogo;
private TextView welcomeText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    Typeface roboto_s = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Roboto-Thin.ttf");
    mLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo_sp);
    welcomeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome_text);
    welcomeText.setTypeface(roboto_s);

    Animation animation2;{
        mLogo.setAlpha(1.0F);
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate_top_to_center);
        mLogo.startAnimation(anim);
    }
    Animation animation3; {
        ObjectAnimator alphaAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(welcomeText, "alpha", 0.0F, 1.0F);
        alphaAnimation.setStartDelay(700);
        alphaAnimation.setDuration(1200);
        alphaAnimation.start();
    }


    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        finish();
        Intent next = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Intro.class);//
        startActivity(next);
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

}

Comment: can you add log output?

Comment: Yes, Please wait for a minute

Comment: btw. is this code in the SplashScreensActivity?

Comment: post logcat and splash activity code and the other activity code which are you calling in splash activity using intent.

Comment: i have 1 mistake in the splashActivity and after solved that, app isnt close but intro activity never starting Even in the first run.

Comment: Did you uninstall the app/cleared cache?

Comment: Yes, Uninstall and Clear Cache and Data

Comment: `Intent i=new Intent(Intro.this,Intro.class);`  -> shouldn't this be `Intent i=new Intent(Intro.this,IntroActivity.class);`

Or did you get it to work already?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: no, it's not worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved with a change in SplashScreenActivity.

So I 've edited the **Handler** codes in the **SplashScreenActivity**:

```
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (settings.getBoolean("isFirstRun", true)) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putBoolean("isFirstRun", false);
                editor.commit();
                Intent next = new Intent(SplashScreensActivity.this, Intro.class);
                startActivity(next);
            } else {
                Intent next2 = new Intent(SplashScreensActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(next2);
                finish();
            }
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

and remove firstRun method from Intro.Java

I hope to be useful